# Drag-drop stops working after EnableMouseinPointer()

Tags: windows, drag-and-drop

I have a windows desktop application that currently works with the traditional `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, `WM_LBUTTONUP`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE`, etc messages.

I thought about giving the new `WM_POINTER*` messages a try, but as soon as I call `EnableMouseinPointer()`, drag drop initiated from the application seems to get messed up.

On a drag-drop attempt within the application, I receive calls in `DragEnter()` and `Drop()` in my IDropTarget object, but not in `DragOver()` and `DragLeave()`.
When I initiate a drag from some other application, and drop in mine, things work fine.

Anyone else here who has given `WM_POINTER*` a try? Any idea why this could be happening?
There doesn’t seem to be anything on msdn regarding this, but not sure if I need to do anything special for drag-drop to work.

If I don’t make the EnableMouseinPointer() call, everything continues to work as it did before.

Comment: Maybe add the relevant code parts so others can look for problems.

Comment: We have the same problem, `EnableMouseInPointer` causes OLE drag drop to fail.